# Join and combine tables to get common rows in a specific column together in Postgres

Tags: postgresql, join, union

I have a couple of tables in Postgres database. I have joined and merges the tables. However, I would like to have common values in a specific column to appear together in the final table (In the end, I would like to perform groupby and maximum value calculation on the table).

The schema of the test tables looks like this:

Schema (PostgreSQL v11)

```
CREATE TABLE table1 (

  id CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  seq CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO table1 (id, seq) VALUES 
  ('UA502', 'abcdef'), ('UA503', 'ghijk'),('UA504', 'lmnop')
;

CREATE TABLE table2 (

  id CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  score FLOAT

);

INSERT INTO table2 (id, score) VALUES 
  ('UA502', 2.2), ('UA503', 2.6),('UA504', 2.8)
;


CREATE TABLE table3 (

  id CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  seq CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL

);

INSERT INTO table3 (id, seq) VALUES 
  ('UA502', 'qrst'), ('UA503', 'uvwx'),('UA504', 'yzab')
;

CREATE TABLE table4 (

  id CHARACTER VARYING NOT NULL,
  score FLOAT

);

INSERT INTO table4 (id, score) VALUES 
  ('UA502', 8.2), ('UA503', 8.6),('UA504', 8.8);

;
```

I performed join and union and oepration of the tables to get the desired columns.

**Query #1**

```
SELECT table1.id, table1.seq, table2.score
    FROM table1 INNER JOIN table2 ON table1.id = table2.id

UNION 

SELECT table3.id, table3.seq, table4.score
    FROM table3 INNER JOIN table4 ON table3.id = table4.id

;
```

The output looks like this:

```
| id    | seq    | score |
| ----- | ------ | ----- |
| UA502 | qrst   | 8.2   |
| UA502 | abcdef | 2.2   |
| UA504 | yzab   | 8.8   |
| UA503 | uvwx   | 8.6   |
| UA504 | lmnop  | 2.8   |
| UA503 | ghijk  | 2.6   |
```

However, the desired output should be:

```
| id    | seq    | score |
| ----- | ------ | ----- |
| UA502 | qrst   | 8.2   |
| UA502 | abcdef | 2.2   |
| UA504 | yzab   | 8.8   |
| UA504 | lmnop  | 2.8   |
| UA503 | uvwx   | 8.6   |
| UA503 | ghijk  | 2.6   |
```

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m8HFX1VdM5ktb4vbuGgkg2/0)

How should I modify my query to get the desired output?

Comment: Maybe I am missing something, but wouldn't `order by id` do this?

Comment: Oh yes!! I missed it :) Thanks for pointing